# Tally words that are in bold by group in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a formula which will count the number of cells which contain bold text at a group level. Here is a snippet of data as an illustrative example:-

[image: Example of the data]

Here is a function created in VBA which can count how many cells are in bold:-

```
Function CountBold(Rng As Range) As Long
Dim Cell As Range
For Each Cell In Rng
    If Cell.Font.Bold Then
        CountBold = CountBold + 1
    End If
Next Cell End Function
```

How could I get this to work so that it counts the number of cells in the Task column that are in bold at group level (the Worker column)?

Comment: What is your expected result, from your example image above?

Comment: Well, if you'd put the `End Function` in the right place it will work when you'd call it like `=CountBold(A2:A12)`, just like any other function. As you can see this specific UDF's argument requires a reference to a range object.

Comment: And how/where would you like the function **to return the bold counting by group**? To return somewhere else unique 'worker' group followed by number of bolded value in column 'Task Name'? Something like `Worker 1 - 2, Worker 2 - 1 etc.? Or the count to be placed in the next column. Even so, I can provide such a solution/function, but how to use it as UDF (in formula)? Where to place it to return correctly? What do you have in your mind, from this point of view? A solution delivering such information at once, will be convenient?

Comment: @CLR the output I would like is such as a table, where Worker 1 = 2, Worker 2 = 1, Worker 3 =  2, Worker 4 = 1 , Worker 5 = 0

Comment: @JvdV, correct, End Function is not in the right place due to my error of copying and pasting into the post above, I know how it works in VBA

Comment: @FaneDuru yes exactly like that output you describe. That would be the simplest way

Comment: Then, try the code I've just posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next code. It will return starting from "C2":

```
Sub countBoldPerGroup()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, i As Long
   Dim dict As Object, arr
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the seet you need
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row
   Set rng = sh.Range("A2:B" & lastR) 'set the range to be processed

   sh.Columns("C:D").ClearContents 'clear the columns where to return
   
   'Load the dictionary with the unique keys and their count per bolded group:
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'set the necessary dictionary
   For i = 1 To rng.rows.count
        If rng.cells(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then _
               dict(rng.cells(i, 2).Value) = dict(rng.cells(i, 2).Value) + 1
   Next i
   
   'Create a 2D array from the dictionary keys and items:
   arr = Application.Transpose(Array(dict.keys, dict.Items))
   
   'write a little header
   sh.Range("C1:D1").Value = Array("Worker", "Work Count")
   'drop the array content in C2:
   sh.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

If something not clear enough, do  not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

**Edited**:

Please, copy the next events in the sheet to be processed code module. Before that, copy the adapted above Sub (only a code line, clearing columns "C:E", to avoid the cases when one group is eliminated and existing last row remains: `sh.Columns("C:D").ClearContents`):

```
Option Explicit

Private BoldCount As Long, lastCellA As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Target.column = 1 And Target.cells.count = 1 Then 'it works only for a single cell change!
        If Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then                          'if no worker in B:B, warning and UnDo:
                MsgBox "A ""Worker"" must exist in Column ""B:B""."
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                  Application.Undo
                Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
      End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If lastCellA = "" Then 'at the beginning:
        countBoldPerGroup       'call the Sub counting bold cells per group
        BoldCount = CountBold 'memorize the bolded (from A:A) cells number
    ElseIf Me.Range(lastCellA).column = 1 Then 'if you left from a cell in A:A:
        If CountBold <> BoldCount Then    'if the counted bold cells <> former BoldCount:
                countBoldPerGroup                 'call the sub counting bold per group
                BoldCount = CountBold            'memorize the new bold count
        End If
     End If
     lastCellA = Target.address                 'memorize the last selected cell address
End Sub

Function CountBold() As Long  'counting the bold cells in A:A:
    Dim lastR: lastR = Me.Range("A" & Me.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long, countB As Long
    For i = 2 To lastR
        If Me.cells(i, 1).Font.Bold Then countB = countB + 1
    Next i
    CountBold = countB
End Function
```

Now play with bolding/un-bolding. But take care that the update will take place **after you leave the bolded cell**!

This is a workaround. As I said, bolding a cell does not trigger any event. So, it calculates the bolded cells of A:A and keep them in a global variable and also memorize the cell previous selected. Then, it evaluates the above mentioned elements to detect if a new running of the above `Sub` is necessary...

Comment: yes this works very well. I was wondering if it is possible for the final counts to be updated automatically if, for example, I was to convert non-bold text to bold, or added in another row and entered bold text into that cell? Many thanks for your contribution so far

Comment: @metaltoaster You did not ask for any automation... Changing the font bold property **does not trigger any event**, to automate the process. The change event (in column A:A) will be triggered if you **enter new cell  value or change an existing one**. Then, the event code may check if the new value is bolded and call the sub, but only in such a case. I can configure the 'BeforeDoubleClick` event to call it, **if you double click on a cell of A:A column**, as a workaround...  Besides that, should I understand that my above code did not answer your question, as it was formulated?

Comment: I know that I didn't ask for automation in OP, no need to highlight. Your solution solved what I was asking as well and I'll mark it as accepted answer. I'll ask my new query in another post and I'll be sure to reference this post.

Comment: @metaltoaster I will also think about a way of automation, even changing the font bold property does not trigger any event. If you tag me (here) and I will be available I will try doing my best. If not, somebody else will maybe find a solution...

Comment: @metaltoaster Please, check the proposed workaround, able to automate the bolding process and send some feedback.

Comment: Mr/FaneDuru, please , How did you identify each group ( on the second column) by using a dictionary? I did not got the concept.

Comment: @Soma A dictionary accepts only unique keys. Using `dict(key)` it returns the dictionary item. If key exists, `dict(key) = dict(key) + 1` increment the dictionary item, **for each occurrence**... You can easily extract the unique keys, and can keep as items any object, array, string etc. Its items can be directly updated, **except the array item**, which needs to be extracted in another array, updated and place it back as item.